# splitting and concatenating a string

Tags: python, string, split, append

I was wondering if python had a built in function similar to

```
string->list
```

and `list->string` in scheme.

So for example I would like to turn 'abc' into `['a','b','c']` and vice versa using a built in function.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

String to list:

```
>>> list('abc')
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

List to string:

```
>>> ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'abc'
```

Answer (score 0):

Split using a list comprehension `[c for c in theString]` .. and join them again using `''.join(theList)`. Other ways exist.